I want to first pull bashrc from a source, then from my .bashrc file
No thanks, I’m done here. No answer needed.

[ -f source anything] is definitely not right at all. test -f requires the next argument to be a filename, source is not a filename; and ] needs to be a completely separate argument.

Beyond that, it's not clear what you're asking -- "pull bashrc from a source" are words I individually understand, but I don't know what you mean to communicate by stringing them together in that order.

Why do you not simply add source /path.../sourceme.bash to the top of your .bashrc?

Please [edit] your question to tell us what you wanted the code if [ -f source /path.../sourceme.bash]; then to do.

At first I thought you wanted to do this on shell startup, but I noticed you never actually said that. So, is that what you want, or are you talking about doing this on-demand? (think, "now that I'm logged in, I can set up my environment to start working.")

What do you mean by "updated from time to time"? If some system-level process is overwriting your .bashrc periodically, that's a problem. Otherwise, you are the only one that updates your .bashrc, so if there is any automating updating going on, you should ensure that sourcing your additional file is included in that process.

ok, thanks for the help figuring out what I was trying to ask, sometimes it is difficult to get things down succinctly. I updated the question. please let me know if this makes more sense, and if you have any ideas.

Your code made things worse as now we can no longer tell if you're asking for help with the part of your code you want bash to interpret or the part you apparently want conda init (whatever that is) to interpret. Please [edit] your question to show a [mcve] about just the problem you need help with. If it's about bash, then just show bash without the conda init stuff and if it's about cond init then just show that (and find a tag for THAT for your question).

OMG, forget it. I'm so sorry for thinking I could ask anything here and get nothing but criticism from 90% of the people. If you don't want to help people, then don't answer.

SSH config is off-topic for Stack Overflow, and so is interactive shell usage to a lesser extent (for reference see the [tag:ssh] and [tag:bash] tags). Instead you can ask on another site like [unix.se] or [su] or [ubuntu.se].

though, in the spirit of a [mre], it'd help to be specific, like, what exactly did you put in your .bashrc (like source ...), then what did you do (like log out and log back in), what did you expect to happen (like "[some variable] should be set to [some value]"), and what happened instead (like "[some variable] was set to [some other value]").

@hiker what everyone's doing so far is trying to help you create a question so we can then help you answer it. You can take that as unhelpful criticism of your question or you can take it as helpful advice on how to improve your question. You're more likely to get a good answer if you treat it as the latter and update your question to provide the [mcve] we're trying to coach you into being able to write, We could alternatively just have downvoted and closed your question with no explanation and no suggestions on what was wrong with it or how to improve it. See [ask].

I don't know what your sourceme.bash is actually doing, and what of its settings you (possibly) invalidate with your own code; but to find out what actually happens, create a bash subshell with bash -x so that you get a trace.

@EdMorton I agree with you to an extent, but I can only make so many people happy. I changed my question the way one person asked me to, and then someone else said it was no good. it's not worth rephrasing my question over and over because someone doesn't like my wording. maybe it was not perfect, but I am sure they understood what I was asking. there are so many complaints about the people on Stack being arrogant and elitist. I have used it a little in the past, some good some bad experiences, so if people don't like my question, suggestions are fine, but competing suggestions are not helpful

Personally, I had no idea what your question was about (or rather I could imagine many things it might have been about). I don't see any competing suggestions in the comments, everyone appears to just be asking for a [mcve] and a statement of what you're trying to do and in what way it's failing so we could help you. Sorry if it came off differently from that on your side of the fence. Just take a look at [ask], and in particular [mcve], and look at other questions that have been upvoted and answered for examples of how to ask a good question.


have language and paths and other things standardized between multiple people

It sounds like this just sets some environment variables (export VAR=value) and does not define any functions or aliases. The difference between only defining environment variables and adding aliases or functions is that aliases and functions must be added at the bashrc level. For this part of the answer, I'll assume it only sets environment variables.
If this is opt-in, each person would need to add this line to the top of their own ~/.bash_profile:
# .bash_profile
. /path.../sourceme.bash

Alternately, if this is opt-out, then you can add it to be sourced when the user logs in by creating a script inside in /etc/profile.d:
# /etc/profile.d/zzz_last.sh
# Let the user opt-out of this by running "touch ~/.dont-sourceme-bro"
if [[ ! -f ~/.dont-sourceme-bro ]]; then
    . /path.../sourceme.bash
fi

It's prefixed with zzz just in case it needs to override a variable previously set via a different script in profile.d; scripts are executed in ASCIIbetical order upon login.
Users will need to log out and then log back in in order to have this apply.
Wait, I want to define functions and aliases too!
Skip the previous section. Just have everyone add this to their own ~/.bashrc instead:
# .bashrc
if [[ -f /path.../sourceme.bash ]]; then
    . /path.../sourceme.bash
fi

You can also apply the first part of this answer to the environment variable portion, then functions and aliases using a different file.

Thanks, @amphetamachine. It is not an opt-out. The source file has functions and links to aliases. It loads specific modules and does a conda initialize. I tried adding the source location at the top, but it didn't work. Thanks; I will keep messing around with it.
